# Groovy: XmlTemplateEngine and SimpleTemplateEngine

Tags: xml, groovy, xslt-1.0

I have been trying to copy node elements from one xml document to an xsl file, so far I found below solution works well:

```
        //file path variables are mocked

        def rep = new XmlParser().parse(new File(*filepath1*))
        def pw = new StringWriter()
        new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(pw)).print(rep)
        rep = pw.toString()

        def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
        def binding = [responsexml:rep]
        def template = engine.createTemplate(new File(*filepath2*)).make(binding)

        new File(*filepath3*).write(template.toString())
```

The templating xsl file looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    ${responsexml}
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After the node elements get copied, the final xsl file looked like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <AAA>
               *SOME CONTENT*
            </AAA>
</xsl:template>
```

Ok...sorry for the long boring background, here is the **question**:
I used `SimpleTemplateEngine`above, which produced me a file with content just as expected, but when I switched to use `XmlTemplateEngine`, the line
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
was removed from the produced xsl file.

I would like to know why the XML engine actually is not working as expected? and possibly this is a very noob question since I am very new to groovy.... so will be very thanksful if anyone can point me to the doc that explains above. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look that http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/text/XmlTemplateEngine.html

XmlTemplateEngine remove xml declaration as a part of processing instructions.

Comment: Thanks, the page may mention the removal of xml declaration implicitly that I only noticed the 'gsp' namespace was removed from that example from 1st time reading it.
So what is the direct benefit of removing those declarations with this engine?